# How to search multiple values for same propertykey in gremlin

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3

What is the best way to get values with same property key?

EDIT: Sorry for changing the question my requirement was to get an employee from either of the departments

I need to fetch all the the employees who work for IT or Sales departments and are being managed by manager with id 123.

I have used

```
g.V().has('managerId',123).out('manages').as('employee')
   .out('worksFor').has('departmentName','IT','Sales')
   .select('employee')
```

where `out('worksAt')` gives department.

Can we do this in a `has()` step or should we use `union()` step like

```
g.V().has('managerId',123).out('manages').as('employee').out('worksFor')
    .union(__.has('departmentName','IT'),__.has('departmentName','Sales')
    .select('employee')
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are probably only missing the [`within` predicate](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#a-note-on-predicates) which is also explained in the context of the [`has` step in the TinkerPop documentation](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#has-step):

```
g.V().has('managerId',123).out('manages').as('employee').out('worksFor').
    has('departmentName',within('IT','Sales')).select('employee')
```

edit: After reading stephen's answer I noticed that I read over the *and* in your question:

> employees who work for IT **and** Sales

That makes my answer of course invalid. I still leave it here just in case that you actually meant *or* as indicated by your later use of the `union` step.

Comment: Hey! How can I query on gremlin-python within method?

Comment: It should work exactly the same way with gremlin-python. You probably just need [some imports](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#gremlin-python-imports).

Answer (score 6):

Here's a sample graph:

```
gremlin> graph = TinkerGraph.open()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0]
gremlin> g = graph.traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0], standard]
gremlin> g.addV("managerId",123).as("manager").
......1>   addV("employee","A").as("A").
......2>   addV("employee","B").as("B").
......3>   addV("department", "IT").as("it").
......4>   addV("department", "Sales").as("sales").
......5>   addE("manages").from("manager").to("A").
......6>   addE("manages").from("manager").to("B").
......7>   addE("worksFor").from("A").to("it").
......8>   addE("worksFor").from("B").to("it").
......9>   addE("worksFor").from("A").to("sales").iterate()
```

In this case, I make it so that employee A is in both "Sales" and "IT", but employee B is only in "IT". Since you said you wanted employees who work in both departments employee A is who should be returned from the query and B should be filtered out.

Note that the use of `within` yields an incorrect answer in that case:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('managerId',123).
......1>   out('manages').
......2>   where(out('worksFor').
......3>         has('department',within('IT','Sales'))).
......4>   valueMap()
==>[employee:[A]]
==>[employee:[B]]
```

Here is the approach if you want both departments:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('managerId',123).
......1>   out('manages').
......2>   where(out('worksFor').
......3>         has('department','Sales')).
......4>   where(out('worksFor').
......5>         has('department','IT')).
......6>   valueMap()
==>[employee:[A]]
```

Comment: Thank you Stephen I have a small doubt can't I use has() step twice to  get the same result

Comment: How ever my requirement was to get all the employees who work either for IT or Sales

Comment: Then Florian Hockmann posted the right answer originally, though i would prefer my answer that uses `within` as you get rid of the `as('employee')` and `select('employee')`. imo, the use of `where` is easier to read/comprehend at a glance.